# How to verify automatic rotation of image carousel?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
<div class='bx-pager'> == $0
    <a href data-slide-index = "0" class = "bx-pager-link-active"> 1 </a>
</div>
<div class='bx-pager'> == $0
    <a href data-slide-index = "1" class = "bx-pager-link"> 2 </a>
</div>
<div class='bx-pager'> == $0
    <a href data-slide-index = "2" class = "bx-pager-link"> 3 </a>
</div>
```

The above is the code of an auto image carousel, that rotates between 3 images, every three seconds.

I am trying to find the most efficient way to verify if the carousel is properly rotating.

Note - the image that is displayed on the page has the class named transformed to "bx-pager-link-active", as opposed to "bx-pager-link" when its inactive.

Comment: Can you take a look at this image's dimension?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "most efficient" and "carousel is properly rotating"...
If you want to check that the carousel is switching to a different anchor element every 3 seconds then I'd probably use loop that checks the "...-active" class switches to the next anchor and then Thread.Sleep for 3 seconds <- Might actually be the first time I've thought of a good reason to use Thread.Sleep in a WebDriver test :D